# Issues with aggregate functions and retrieving columns while joining tables

Tags: sql, t-sql, aggregate-functions

If I group by the name that I assigned to a column (*FullName*), I get an error message. But if I group by  "*per.FirstName + ' ' + per.LastName*" then everything works. Why does it happen?

The below query failed

```
   SELECT per.FirstName + ' ' + per.LastName as FullName, format((Round(sum(had.totaldue),2)),'C') as total_sales
   FROM SALES.SalesOrderHeader AS had
   JOIN person.Person as peron per.BusinessEntityID = had.SalesPersonID
   group by FullName
   order by total_sales;
```

> *Query_1_result:*
> An error message:
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
> Invalid column name 'FullName'

Instead of "FullName", I used the expression that was deriving it, and it worked.

```
SELECT per.FirstName + ' ' + per.LastName as FullName, format((Round(sum(had.totaldue),2)),'C') as total_sales
FROM SALES.SalesOrderHeader AS had
join person.Person as per
on per.BusinessEntityID = had.SalesPersonID
group by per.FirstName + ' ' + per.LastNameorder by total_sales;
```

> *Query_2_result:*
> The table showing total sales amounts by each sales person.

Tried to add a job title column by joining another table to the above query, but it failed.

```
SELECT per.FirstName + ' ' + per.LastName as FullName,emp.JobTitle, format((Round(sum(had.totaldue),2)),'C') as total_sales
FROM SALES.SalesOrderHeader AS had
JOIN person.Person as per
on per.BusinessEntityID = had.SalesPersonID
JOIN HumanResources.Employee AS emp
on emp.BusinessEntityID = per.BusinessEntityIDgroup by per.firstname + ' ' + per.LastNameorder by total_sales;
```

> *Query_3_result:*
> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
> Column 'HumanResources.Employee.JobTitle' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Assuming SQL Server as RDBMS. you cannot use an alias in `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thank you! I am new to SQL and programming in general. Would appreciate any help.

Could you please show me how should I write the query to retrieve the job title as well? Tried different things but in the end spent an hour or two trying :(

Comment: Just add full expression of *FullName* and JobTitle column in `GROUP BY` clause required since you use aggregate function, `SUM`.